# BootStrap Jumbotron width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a jumbotron bootstrap width that covers the whole page. I want to implement a style where it doesn't covers the whole page. Is there any attribute I can apply that I can adjust the width?

```
/* style -- this is the stylesheet */

.jumbotron {
    font-size: 17px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Can you add more info? The jumbotron is usually the width of the div class="container" (generally 1120px wide) or div class="container-fluid" (100% of the screen). I wouldn't change the width of the .jumbotron to 5px. You'll never get it to render...

Comment: Edit: Never mind, the HTML is there but does not show up due to your formatting. Fixed this in an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.mycustom-jumbotron {
  border:10px solid #003366;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="jumbotron mycustom-jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Bootstrap</h1>
  <p>Bootstrap Web Design</p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.jumbotron-test {
    font-size: 17px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50%;
    text-align:Center;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-test">
  <h1>Jumbotron</h1>
  <p>Testing Jumbo tron</p> 
</div>
```